# .NET CORE under Ubuntu 16.04 - Logging permissions

Tags: asp.net, logging, asp.net-core, .net-core, serilog

**Is there any special CHMOD or any permission necessary to make an ASP NET MVC under .NET Core 2.0 log?** On my windows dev machine the log is generated normally but not on my production machine.

I have an Web App running on a Ubuntu 16.04 DigitalOcean Droplet. Two days after every deploy it starts to throw a NullObjectException that I'm not able to trace properly and stops whenever I restart kestrel, even allowing the developer exception page to be shown (it is not verbose enough cuz I can't see where in my code the last call is made - it only shows native framework calls.

Comment: You said two days after deployment , so the app continues to run normally for 2 days ?  Also yes you will need the process account which is used to run the dotnet application to have write permissions on the log folder.

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee Tks for the quick answser. Yes, it does run normally for 2 days and I just discovered by making the status code of the API requests log to the console and discovered that it is due to the api generating invalid tokens (I add them to the authorization headers and get a 401 on every authorized call). Coincidence or not, the tokenoptons are set to make generated tokens valid for 2 days but that should not be a problem cuz I ask for a new token every time the user logs in. I guess I will have to learn more about JWT mechanics